# Running a Node.JS background process for Twitter streaming API in Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, twitter, google-cloud-functions

I want to deploy a Node.JS script to Firebase that listens for new tweets using Twitter's streaming API, and then stores each tweet in the Firebase Database. How do I deploy this script and make sure that it runs 24/7?

As an example, consider the following (simplified) code, based on NPM [Twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit) package:

```
var stream = T.stream('statuses/sample')

stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
  // write data to Firebase Database here
})
```

I looked into [Firebase Cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), but that's not what I want, because they are triggered by an event. I also saw there is [Firebase Queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue), but I don't really want to queue the process: I just want it to run all the time. Is this possible currently with Firebase hosting?

An alternative would be to create a Twitter recipe with [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) that calls a Webbook. However, I want to store tweets from many different users, so it's not a very flexible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting can't run any code.  Cloud Functions can run code, but not indefinitely, and only in response to defined triggers.

Consider instead using multiple IFTTT with a Cloud Function as a webhook to receive tweets that meet some search criteria, [as implemented in this project](https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/d61cbe63b3a2f90799d9651451adfcfa).  You can set up multiple IFTTT applets if you need multiple queries to be aggregated in one place.  This may be your best bet if you don't want to maintain your own server.

Comment: Thanks Doug, let me try implementing using IFTTT.

Any idea if there are other services that do allow you to do this? And how would I search for this?