# Load Tweets live to be displayed on front-end

Tags: firebase, twitter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm setting up a server using firebase and want to load Tweets dynamically/live from Twitter by filtering them by hashtags.

Basically what I want to do is integrate a live feed of sorts from twitter to load tweets about Bitcoin and other Cryptocurrencies on my webpage. I'm using Vue CLI for the front end.

I've done extensive research on twitter, signed up for a developer account and had many go's and tries, but without any luck. I am really stuck as there does not seem to be any way to fetch tweets and then display the, live on my front end.

Ì actually do not have any code to show, as I do not even understand how it would be possible.

I've set-up the backend successfully on firebase and do not have any issues with CRUD operations and Authentications etc. What I need is to dynamically load(live) tweets from twitter and then filter them using a hashtag.

I haven't been successful at even understanding if this is possible, so I haven't received any error messages. It seems to me that you can only let users sign in and then they can post tweets through an integrated API.

Answer (score 3):

You have to open a twitter stream in your backend and send the results to the frontend using sockets, if you want it to be updated in real time.

You can check this out to get you started:

[Running a Node.JS background process for Twitter streaming API in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513767/running-a-node-js-background-process-for-twitter-streaming-api-in-firebase)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Haris has said, another alternative would be to use SSE (Server-Sent Events) since you are only concerned of unilateral communication rather than bilateral communication. A tutorial for this action, however, will depend on the backend framework you are using.

Feel free to consult the following link that suites your framework on how to use SSEs:

[Server-Sent Events with Node](https://jasonbutz.info/2018/08/server-sent-events-with-node/)

[Real-Time Web Apps with Server-Sent Events (Express JS)](http://bayn.es/real-time-web-applications-with-server-sent-events-pt-1/)

[Server-Sent Events with Fastify (fastify-sse)](https://github.com/lolo32/fastify-sse#readme)

[Server-Sent Events with Hapi (SuSiE)](https://github.com/mtharrison/susie)